# How to colorize unread links phpBB

Tags: html, css, styles, themes, phpbb

i've been searching everywhere but couldn't find the answer for my question. 
first of all, here is my style, or my forum link : [www.fer-play.info](http://www.fer-play.info)

As you can see, i have the Cynthia `style` prosilver based. It's a little bit unclear, so i wanted to colorise those unread links. I searched everywhere, but didn't succeed. I even edited the css files as some users said, but it didn't work. so could you please help me? 
Thx in advance!

if possible, detailed instruction how and where to edit , because i'm a begginer

```
phpBB version 3.0.12
```

Answer (score 0):

**In CSS**

a:link means unvisited link.

a:visited means visited link.

a:hover means a link when the mouse pointer is on it.

a:active means a link when it's clicked right now.

So if you want to change unvisted link's color to red you can use this code:

```
<head>
<style>
a:unvisited {color:red;}
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Do i have to add that on the bottom somewhere or do i have to find that and edit it? Thx